# Edge browser settings to open Excel

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have an aspx page with the button "Export to Excel". When I click the export excel button in EDGE browser it opens in text format(.txt) instead of Excel. It is working fine in IE browser.  To open Excel in Edge Browser  what settings are required to make it work.
  if possible please provide the steps to make the settings.
Code:

```
       Dim sExcelURL As String = "Lst_Excel.aspx?SortBy=" & 
         ViewState("colSorted") & "&SortDir=" & ViewState("dirSorted"). In 
   Lst_Excel.aspx it is mentioned : Response.ContentType = 
   "application/vnd.ms-excel" Response.Charset = "" Me.EnableViewState = False
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to provide any sample code for producing the issue. Does your code save the Excel file? Did you try to check whether the file gets created properly? Which version of the Edge browser you are using for this test? Please try to provide detailed information about the issue. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi, when click export to excel it will give options to save,open. Files are created properly using IE.In the code it is used as below  Dim sExcelURL As String = "List_Excel.aspx?SortBy=" & ViewState("colSorted") & "&SortDir=" & ViewState("dirSorted"). In List_Excel.aspx it is mentioned : Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Response.Charset = ""
            Me.EnableViewState = False

Comment: it is opening for all other users except one user browser edge

Comment: I suggest you do not post the code in a comment. Try to include it in your original post. Please inform us, which version of the Edge browser you are using? Try to set the Excel as the default application for opening .xlsx files on your machine. Check whether it helps to fix this issue.

Comment: try to set as dafult application

Comment: Please inform us, what result you got? did it resolve the issue? Please inform us, which version of the Edge browser you are using?

Comment: Version 80.0.361.111

Comment: Does file gets downloaded with .xlsx extension or with .txt extension?

Comment: files downloaded with .txt extension

Comment: Can you try to post a sample code that we can run on our side to test this issue with the Edge Chromium browser? The code you provided above is not giving much idea about the issue.